# Load stored RSA public/private key from disk?

Tags: java, android, cryptography, rsa

independent from the fact that the private key should be encrypted (which happens independently from this question): I'm generating RSA key pairs using this code:

```
KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");

kpg.initialize(2048);
KeyPair keyPair = kpg.generateKeyPair();
privKey = (RSAPrivateKey)keyPair.getPrivate();
pubKey = (RSAPublicKey)keyPair.getPublic();     
byte[] data=privKey.getEncoded();
...
byte[] data=pupKey.getEncoded();
```

The contents of data are binary and not Base 64 encoded or something like that.

When I store the contents of data somewhere and want to load them later - how can I do that? RSAPrivateKey and RSAPublicKey do not have any constructors/loader or something like that...

Answer (score 3):

It's confusing, but to go *from* a java [Key](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/Key.html) *to* bytes for storage use the [getEncoded()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/Key.html#getEncoded%28%29) method. To go the other way, *from* bytes *to* a [Key](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/Key.html), use a [KeyFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/KeyFactory.html).

If your key is a private key, then to go *from* bytes back *to* a private key create a [PKCS8EncodedKeySpec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/spec/PKCS8EncodedKeySpec.html). To go *from* bytes *to* an RSA public key use an [X509EncodedKeySpec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/spec/X509EncodedKeySpec.html). These [KeySpecs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/spec/KeySpec.html) are then supplied to an instance of an appropriate [KeyFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/KeyFactory.html) to recover the [PublicKey](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/PublicKey.html) and [PrivateKey](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/PrivateKey.html) objects.

Comment: +1. I think it has to be a key factory created using `KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA")`.