# How to convert from String to PublicKey?

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, public-key-encryption

I've used the following code to convert the public and private key to a string

```
KeyPairGenerator keyPairGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
keyPairGen.initialize(2048);
KeyPair          keyPair    = keyPairGen.genKeyPair();
PublicKey        publicKey  = keyPair.getPublic();
PrivateKey       privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();
String publicK = Base64.encodeBase64String(publicKey.getEncoded());
String privateK = Base64.encodeBase64String(privateKey.getEncoded());
```

Now I'm trying to convert it back to public ad private key

```
PublicKey publicDecoded = Base64.decodeBase64(publicK);
```

I'm getting error of cannot convert from byte[] to public key. So I tried like this

```
PublicKey publicDecoded = new SecretKeySpec(Base64.decodeBase64(publicK),"RSA");
```

This leads to error like below

```
java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Neither a public nor a private key
```

Looks like I'm doing wrong key conversion here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Load stored RSA public/private key from disk?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19366498/load-stored-rsa-public-private-key-from-disk)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting Strings to encryption keys and vice versa java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755057/converting-strings-to-encryption-keys-and-vice-versa-java)

Comment: Thanks guys. Now I'm able to successfully convert it back to PublicKey using X509EncodedKeySpec. I do searched before posting the question, but what I've seen was mostly involves conversion of SecretKey but not public and private keys.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I don't think you can use the `SecretKeySpec` with RSA.

This should do:

```
byte[] publicBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(publicK);
X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicBytes);
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PublicKey pubKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec);
```

And to decode the private use `PKCS8EncodedKeySpec`

Comment: thanks. I forgot about private key. I'll use PKCS8EncodedKeySpec for private key.

Comment: Which `import` does the above `Base64` come from?

Comment: @Hooli I think it's from org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.
also, you could use Base64.getDecoder().decode(publicK) in the java.util if you use Java 1.8

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing but am getting java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException ... when it tries to execute the last line .. keyfactory.generatePublic(keySpec)

Comment: @HayaRaed ask a new question, you'll get far more attention.

Comment: How do you do this with javascript?

Comment: @RenzCarlo Ask a new question. By asking on an answer only that person (me in this case) gets notified about your comment. So you're asking 1 person rather than the whole of stack overflow and I am 100% not your guy when it comes to JS.